# Laravel paypal form submit validation

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel, paypal

I am using the paypal API in my Laravel project and when the user clicks on submit I want to create and execute a paypal payment. The problem is that paypal are processed with javascript the following way:
**my-page.blade.php:**

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $('#submit').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault()

            $('#payments').fadeIn('slow')

            var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = '{{ route('change-company-activity-subject-paypal-create') }}'

            var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = '{{ route('change-company-activity-subject-paypal-execute') }}'

            paypal.Button.render({

                env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'

                commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

                payment: function() {
                    return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL, {_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'}).then(function(data) {
                        // console.log(data)
                        return data.id
                    });
                },

                // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
                onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                    console.log(data)
                    // Set up the data you need to pass to your server
                    var data = {
                        paymentID: data.paymentID,
                        payerID: data.payerID,
                        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                    };

                    // Make a call to your server to execute the payment
                    return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, data)
                        .then(function (res) {
                            res = JSON.parse(res)
                            console.log(res)
                            window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                        });
                }

            }, '#paypal-button');

            console.log('paypal')  
        })
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

When the payment is completed the `window.alert()` function is called in this case. I've thought of doing `$('#form').submit()` so the form is submitted after the payment is executed. My form has back-end validation rules and it redirects you if your inputs does not pass a certain validation rule. The problem with that is that the user's money can be taken and the form not submitted. How can I avoid this problem ? How to show the Paypal login form and execute the payment only when the validations have passed when Javascript is used to show the login form and execute the payment ?

Comment: Does Paypal not have an Automatic Response URL in case the user pays but closes the browser? The url will get called by Paypal on a later point in time with the status of the payed order. Paypal will send post data to this url. Even if you pay and click away the page and not submit the form.

Comment: How about having multiple steps? In the first step(s) you process all the stuff managed in your backend and when everything is in order you let the user pick a payment method or confirm payment and submit to paypal. If you don't want to store the data in the db before payment is confirmed, which is sometimes necessary due to legal requirements, you can save the data in the session and then do your submit based on the result from the payment request. If the payment fails you might want to clear the session, if it went through you persist the (previously validated) data from the session.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has two more parameters you can use:

```
paypal.Button.render({
  payment: function() {},
  onAuthorize: function(data) {},
  onError: function(err) {
    // error handling
  },
  onCancel: function(data, actions) {
    // cancel handling
  },
});
```